# alert() script popping up before website's content loads (even though I inserted tag at bottom of html file)

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting on JavaScript and I'm following along this online course where it claims that if I insert `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page just before the `<body>` closing tag I should be able to see the website render first followed by the JavaScript code, but it is actually executing the other way around, the JavaScript code executes first and it's not until after I click  "OK" on the message popping up that I'm able to see the website fully rendered.

Here is the code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>JavaScript Basics</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Where to place your JavaScript code.</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**scripts.js**

```
alert("This text should appear after page is fully rendered");
```

I honestly don't know if this is how the code is supposed to work. **Do** `alert();` **scripts always execute first?** Maybe the browser has something to do with it? (I'm using the latest version of Chrome). Anyhow, a well explained answer of what's happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do something more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>JavaScript Basics</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Where to place your JavaScript code.</h1>
  </div>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
      alert('This should now load after the page.');
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `window.onload = fun...` says "wait until the page has finished loading". Depending on what the browsers decide to (with images, layout, plugins etc.), this may or may not work for you.

Or even something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>JavaScript Basics</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Where to place your JavaScript code.</h1>
  </div>
  <script async defer src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this example, the `async` attribute means "grab this script file in the background" and the `defer` means "wait until the page has loaded to execute it".

Comment: Very curious about the down votes. Keen to hear why.